# How to ignore case in Ext Js while Field Mapping

Tags: extjs, extjs4, case-insensitive

I am using same Ext Js model for different API's. But in some of the API's i will get field as 'SupplierID' and in some api's response I will get it as 'supplierId'.

I am looking for an option to ignore the case while mapping in Ext JS framework.

```
fields:
  [
    { name: 'SupplierID', type: 'int', mapping: 'supplierId' },
  ]
```

Please advice is there any option in Ext Js to ignore the case while filed name mapping. So that i can avoid creating multiple models.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calculate:

```
fields: [
    { name: 'SupplierID', type: 'int',
        calculate: function (data) {
            return data.SupplierID || data.supplierId;
        }
    },
]
```